# How to use distinct with agrregation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

```
    d = collection.aggregate([
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "NS": "fragrance"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "chatter_master_data_Dish_care",
                        "localField": "doc_id",
                        "foreignField": "doc_id",
                        "as": "inventory_docs"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$unwind": "$inventory_docs"
                },
                {
                    "$match" : {
                        "inventory_docs.Category": {"$regex" : re.compile("Dish Care", re.IGNORECASE)}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": "$inventory_docs.Category"
                    }
                },
                { "$limit": 5 }
        ])
```

How to use distinct in mongodb aggregations

Hi here i am trying to get **distinct** result as per **"inventory_docs.Category"**
I found the distinct in **db.collection.distinct()**
but counld not find distinct using aggregate.

PLease have a look.

```
{
  "": "11049",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics": "",
  "crawled_at": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location_county": "",
  "title": "Homewood Suites by Hilton Lake Mary",
  "index": "14027",
  "location_country": "USA",
  "content_noun_adj": " great room sofa little uncomfortable room dishwash sink water while rest great dishwash didbpot coffee smell",
  "location_longitude": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_bio_tag_list": "",
  "doc_id": "US_Dish Care USA _Consumer opinions_2016-01-03_14027",
  "title_norm": "homewood suites by hilton lake mary ",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location_latitude": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_age": "",
  "content_pre_processed": "   great room ! sofas little uncomfortable and room smelled because dishwash er and sink had not had any water ran through it in a while but the rest was great . we just ran the dishwash er and didbpot of coffee to get smell out and it worked .",
  "human_review_status": "reviewed",
  "location": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location_longitude": "",
  "date": "2016-01-03",
  "channel": "earned",
  "language": "eng",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_gender": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_family_status": "",
  "title_lemmatized": " homewood suite by hilton lake mary",
  "location_latitude": "",
  "site_id": "2965385.0",
  "title_pre_processed": " homewood suites by hilton lake mary",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location_country": "",
  "Country": "US",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_picture_url": "",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5cd91749e42b8c2438d837ab"
  },
  "content_noun": " room sofa room sink water while rest didbpot coffee smell",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_sentiment": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_date": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_title": "",
  "Category": "Dish Care USA ",
  "ratings_raw": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location_state": "",
  "site_name": "Expedia",
  "content_norm": " great room! sofas little uncomfortable and room smelled because dishwash er and sink had not had any water ran through it in a while but the rest was great. we just ran the dishwash er and didbpot of coffee to get smell out and it worked. ",
  "all-in-one": "['homewood suites by hilton lake mary', ' great room! sofas little uncomfortable and room smelled because dishwash er and sink had not had any water ran through it in a while but the rest was great. we just ran the dishwash er and didbpot of coffee to get smell out and it worked.', '']",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_marital_status": "",
  "title_noun": " homewood suite hilton lake mary",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_location_city": "",
  "content_parsed": " great room! sofas little uncomfortable and room smelled because dishwash er and sink had not had any water ran through it in a while but the rest was great. we just ran the dishwash er and didbpot of coffee to get smell out and it worked. ",
  "sentiment": "positive",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_job_list": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_url": "",
  "title_noun_adj": " homewood suite hilton lake mary",
  "site_type": "Consumer opinions",
  "synthesio_rank": "5.0",
  "ratings_normalized": "",
  "title_parsed": "homewood suites by hilton lake mary ",
  "content_lemmatized": "   great room ! sofa little uncomfortable and room smell because dishwash er and sink have not have any water run through it in a while but the rest be great . we just run the dishwash er and didbpot of coffee to get smell out and it work .",
  "content": "Great room! Sofas little uncomfortable and room smelled because dishwasher and sink had not had any water ran through it in a while but the rest was great. We just ran the dishwasher and didbpot of coffee to get smell out and it worked.",
  "url": "https://www.expedia.com/Hotel.h118283.Hotel-Information",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_url": "",
  "twitter_retweeted_status_author_demographics_affinity_list": ""
}
```

This is the sample documents of result
But, content column is coming duplicate.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: i want distinct without grouping. I don't want count or some. is there any way?

Comment: Then please show some sample collections and the output you need

Comment: The document is very big.the inventory.category is repeting . So i wants to try distinct of that only

Comment: You have to use $group before $limit query. I think thats the only way in aggregation.

Comment: Please check the question. I changed as you said

Comment: But it is not working

Comment: You wrongly used $group. In $group just replace `"inventory_docs.Category"` with `"$inventory_docs.Category"` . and it will work.

Comment: "$group": {
                    "_id": "$inventory_docs.Category"
                }

Comment: like this? as above comment

Comment: still not working bro.

Comment: yes. correct...

Comment: check the question. I added the same on it also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193246/discussion-between-vikash-singh-and-soubhagya-pradhan).

Comment: Check for `$addToSet` with `$group`

Comment: Could you please edit in question? I never used it before

Comment: Please add some sample documents.

Comment: Added in the question itself. PLease have a look